# Does Ontario government fund OTC medications "prescribed" by a M.D. not covered by employer's drug plan?

Tags: ontario

My Doctor of Medicine insists on a ***prohibitively expensive*** OTC (Over the Counter) medication for me, as it can't be substituted with anything whether prescription or OTC. But I can't afford it!  To try to convince employer's drug plan, my M.D. even wrote a "prescription" for this OTC medication. I showed this "prescription" to my employer's drug plan, but drug plan still refuses to cover this OTC medication.

Can the government of Ontario pay, or subsidize, this OTC medication for me?

How can I request financial assistance from governments to pay for this OTC medication?

Comment: Not really a personal finance question, per se. More one about the Canadian health care system. There has to be a Stack where that would be in topic, but I'm not convinced this is it

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is off topic for Money SE. I don't know if it would be on topic for any SE site.

Comment: Get a second opinion and ask the new doctor if there is an equally good but less expensive treatment. There may not be. Beyond that, details of the Canadian health system are not really Personal Finance, though managing your health budget could be.